# Applying clustering to predicted values

Tags: regression, time-series, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I am using clustering techniques such as hierarchical clustering trees to create an index fund modeled on the S&P500 with the correlation between the returns of individual stocks being used as the distance metric.

I was wondering if I could build a regression model first with the returns as the target variable and then perform hierarchical clustering on it, to see if there are any gains in performance.

Being a bit new to DS, I am not sure if this would work well over just performing hierarchical clustering. Are there any other ways in which I can go about solving this problem? And, is my new methodology correct from a DS perspective?